# Laravel firstOrNew

Tags: laravel

So I am fetching some data every hour from google, and I want to make sure that if I have the rows in database to update them instead of creating duplicates.

Example:

```
$googleResponse->map(function ($row) {
    $es = Google::firstOrNew($row);
    $es->update($row);
});
```

Question: does `firstOrNew()` first checks if the row its in the database if so then it returns the result to `$es` variable so then I could perform an update instead : `$es->update($row);` does it work that way ?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent):

> The `firstOrNew` method, like `firstOrCreate` will **attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes**. However, **if a model is not found, a new model instance will be returned**. Note that the model returned by `firstOrNew` has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call `save` manually to persist it

Emphasis mine.